# cvLoadImage() + cvShowImage() from openCV shows a grey box

Tags: c++, opencv

When I run the following code, images are saved and I can see them and that they are what I want in the directory, but the calls to display them bring up a cascade of 20 windows, none of which contain the images I want to load; all the windows are just grey.

```
  for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
  {
     img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
     num = intToString(i);
     fname = base + num + jpg;
     winName = base + num; 

     cvSaveImage( fname.c_str(), img );
     //img = cvLoadImage(fname.c_str(), -1);
     cvNamedWindow(winName.c_str(), CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
     cvMoveWindow(winName.c_str(), 15*i, 15*i);       //cascade windows
     cvShowImage(winName.c_str(), img);
  }
```

The line that I have commented out is where I've tried reloading the image after saving it, but I still get the same results. Anyone know what my issue is?

Comment: IIRC `cvQueryFrame` returns a pointer to an internal image, does it work if use you `cvCloneImage` and display the clone instead (the cloned image will need freeing at a later point)?

Comment: cvQueryFrame returns a IplImage*. I tried your suggestions and no, I get the same results. It appears that cvCloneImage also returns a IplImage*. Also according to the dosumentation, (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#cvarr , http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_Highgui.htm#decl_cvShowImage) cvShowImage() accepts a IplImage* as an argument

Comment: What I was referring to was the part in the [documentation](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_Highgui.htm#decl_cvQueryFrame) where it says "The grabbed frame is stored internally.". As I didn't see anything immediately wrong with your code I figured that might be the cause, but I guess not.

Comment: @Joshua: yes you can answer your own question and even accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by calling `cvWaitKey()`. From the docs: *Note: This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event processing*